# Codeigniter ->> Аномальная нагрузка на сервер БД

Tags: codeigniter

Всем привет, помогите разобраться..

Хостер пожаловался "Аномальная нагрузка на сервер БД" на большую нагрузку в коде:

```
function searchTutor($param1 = '', $param2 = '', $param3 = '')
{   
    //echo "Under Construction";die();
    $this->data['search_data']  = array();
    $query_tail = " GROUP BY  u.id ORDER BY u.is_premium = 1";
    $condition_location         = " AND 1=1 ";
    $condition_subject          = " AND 1=1 ";
    $condition_experience       = " AND 1=1 ";
    $condition_tutor_type       = " AND 1=1 ";

    /**
    * 
    * Common Query
    * with all condition predefined
    * 
    */
    $query = "  SELECT 
                    u.*, 
                    ts.subject_id, 
                    s.subject_name, 
                    l.location_name, 
                    (SELECT pl.location_name
                    FROM ".$this->db->dbprefix( 'locations' )." pl
                    WHERE pl.id = l.parent_location_id
                    ) AS parent_location_name,
                    tt.tutor_type
                FROM
                    dt_users u, dt_tutor_subjects ts, dt_tutor_locations tl, 
                    dt_subjects s, dt_locations l, 
                    dt_tutor_types tt, dt_tutor_selected_types tst,
                    dt_users_groups ug
                WHERE 
                    ug.group_id         = 3                 AND
                    u.active            = 1                 AND
                    ts.subject_id       = s.id              AND
                    u.location_id       = l.id              AND
                    u.id                = ug.user_id        AND
                    tt.tutor_type_id    = tst.tutor_type_id ";
```

Может где-то что-то убрать или добавить? Дайте совет где копать.. Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Сделайте `EXPLAIN` вашего запроса и посмотрите, на что он тратит больше всего времени. И перепишите ваш запрос с использованием `JOIN`. Выглядит лучше и условие `WHERE` не засоряет

Comment: спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать индексы для начало, вот статья как это сделать
https://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D1%81+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8+%D0%B2+MySQL